# Transferring struct of mixed types to same struct in different memory location

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct, static

I'm trying to make a small routine that will allow me to make two copies of a struct via pointers and transferring data from one struct to the other only if the other struct contains no data at that point. I am successful with copying the first string over (struct member a) and the second struct member is ok, but the third and fourth are incorrect.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

struct A{
    char a[4];
    long b;
    unsigned long c;
    char d;
};

int main(){
    char mb[600];
    struct A *m1=(struct A*)mb;
    char *p=(char*)m1;
    struct A *m2=(struct A*)(mb+100);
    char *pp=(char*)m2;
    memcpy(m1->a,"123",4);
    m1->b=-123;
    m1->c=123;
    m1->d='X';
    m2->b=-456;
    unsigned long q=sizeof(m2);
    while (q-- > 0){
        if (*pp=='\0'){*pp=*p;}
        pp++;p++;
    }
    printf("A=%s B=%ld C=%ld D=%c\n",m2->a,m2->b,m2->c,m2->d);
}
```

Compilation of the code works fine. When I do run it, I see these results:

```
A=123 B=-456 C=0 D=
```

What I'm expecting instead is:

```
A=123 B=-456 C=123 D=X
```

I don't want to rewrite the code so that I individually check the value of each member for data. The struct I will work with will be much larger later on and checking each member using strcmp or direct comparison will take up alot of lines of code. I'm looking for something more compact.

What can I do to fix this?

## UPDATE:

I changed my code and now tried using this while loop instead of the one above:

```
    while (q-- > 0){
if (pp[q]=='\0'){pp[q]=p[q];}
}
```

and the results are still the same (not what I want).

Comment: How do you define "contains no data"?  Zero is data.

Comment: I meant to say null values

Comment: Casting a character array to a structure is rather unsafe (and generally yields undefined behavior), due to alignment considerations. And your actual problem of course is with `if (*pp=='\0'){*pp=*p;}`, since you have plenty of zeros in each one of those structures. For example, `unsigned long c = 123` contains only one character which is **NOT** 0, and all the rest (3 or 7 characters) **ARE* zeros).

Comment: `long`, `unsigned long`, and `char` do not have null values.  (They can be *zero*, but that's different.)

Comment: You're vulnerable to memory alignment problems, especially on 64-bit machines.  The offset of 100 is a multiple of 4, which is adequate for the structure on a 32-bit machine, but it is not a multiple of 8 which might well be the required alignment on an 64-bit machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you’re relying on `mb` being initialized to all zeros, which seems to have happened incidentally when you ran it, but is not guaranteed. If you want it to be initialized to all zeros (and it looks like you do), do that explicitly:

```
memset(mb, 0, sizeof(mb));
```

That said, your problem is that you’re only copying `sizeof(m2)` bytes. `m2` is a pointer, so `sizeof(m2)` is the size of a pointer, *not* the size of `struct A`. You probably want `sizeof(*m2)` instead.